# Search presence of pattern in multiple files

Tags: shell, unix, command-line, grep

I need to make sure that all the files which I find in a parent directory have a particular pattern or not.
Example:

```
./a/b/status: *foo*foo
./b/c/status: bar*bar
./c/d/status: foo
```

The command should return false as file 2 does not have a foo.
I am trying below but dont have clue on how to achieve this in single command.

```
find . -name "status" | xargs grep -c "foo"
```

Answer (score 1):

`-c` option counts the number of times the pattern is found. You wouldn't need `find`, rather use `-r` and `--include` option for grep.

```
$ grep -r -c foo --include=status
```

`-r` does a recursive search for patterh `foo` for files that match `status`.

Example. I have four files in three directories. Each have a single line;

```
$ cat a/1.txt b/1.txt b/2.txt c/1.txt 
foobar
bar
foo
bazfoobar
```

With the above `grep`, you would get something like this,

```
$ grep -ir -c foo --include=1.txt
a/1.txt:1
b/1.txt:0
c/1.txt:1
```

Comment: 1. Does this grep for pattern in the entire directory and then include only the searches in "included" file? That would be way too slow as find reduces search space for me.

Comment: Yes, `-r` option does a recursive search for the file in the `--include` and then search for the pattern.

Answer (score 1):

You can count the number of files that do not contain "foo", if number> 0 it means that there is at least one file that does not contain "foo" :

```
find . -type f -name "status" | xargs grep -c "foo" | grep ':0$' | wc -l
```

or

```
find . -type f -name "status" | xargs grep -c "foo" | grep -c ':0$'
```

or
optimized using iamauser answer (thanks) :

```
grep -ir -c "foo" --include=status | grep -c ':0$'
```

if all files in the tree are named "status", you can use the more simple commande line :

```
grep -ir -c "foo"  | grep -c ':0$'
```

with check

```
r=`grep -ir -c foo  | grep -c ':0$'`
if [ "$r" != "0" ]; then
   echo "false"
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want `find` to output a list of files that can be read by `xargs`, then you need to use:

```
find . -name "status" -print0 | xargs -0 grep foo` to avoid filenames with special characters (like spaces and newlines and tabs) in them.
```

But I'd aim for something like this:

```
find . -name "status" -exec grep "foo" {} \+
```

The `\+` to terminate the `-exec` causes `find` to append all the files it finds onto a single instance of the `grep` command. This is much more efficient than running `grep` once for each file found, which it would do if you used `\;`.

And the default behaviour of `grep` will be to show the filename and match, as you've shown in your question. You can alter this behaviour with options like:

- `-h` ... don't show the filename
- `-l` ... show only the files that match, without the matching text,
- `-L` ... show only the files that DO NOT match - i.e. the ones without the pattern.

This last one sounds like what you're actually looking for.

Answer (score 0):

```
find . -name 'status' -exec grep -L 'foo' {} + | awk 'NF{exit 1}'
```

The exit status of the above will be 0 if all files contain 'foo' and 1 otherwise.